# How to send success message to javascript from a method in java?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

User need to provide a specific password to be authorized to access a specific page.

I show a form and if user entered a correct password will be redirected to a new page otherwise a message need to be shown indicating that password is wrong. How can I implement it ?

At the moment, I can show the "wrong password" message using following code but how to redirect user if password is correct.

I might be able to meet the requirement if I could amend the return code of xmlhttp object.

```
function auth(){
    var form = $('#form').serialize();
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("background").style.display = "Block";
            document.getElementById("box").style.display = "Block";
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        } 
    }
    xmlhttp.open("get","../authenticate?"+form,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
  }
```

**Java**

```
public String authenticate()
{
   if(user is authenticated)
      return a success parameter to JavaScript
   else
     return a wrong password message to JavaScript
}
```

**Additional information**

Backend is Java.

I know I can use window.location.href to redirect but need to make sure user is authenticated before redirecting.

Comment: let me know what is the negative vote for ?

Comment: Is this *really* a Java question?

Comment: it is related to java, I thought, those who know java may have a better solution. in addition some times people asks for backend language as well.

Comment: you can use `window.location.href = whereever you want to redirect to`

Comment: @harsha I know but how to know user is authenticated ? if is not need to show a message not to redirect

Comment: Well, from the backend , you can send a response as 0 or 1 if the user is authenticated or not. and check the response in javascript. If 1 , redirect , if 0 , show message

Comment: I have noticed that but how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to return a page with success as its text and use the following

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText.trim() == 'Success')
            {
                 redirect code
            }
            else{
                     show error message
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.getJSON( url, myDataForTheServer)
    .done(function (dataReturned) {
      console.log(dataReturned);
    })
    .fail(function (response, status, statusText) {
      console.log(status + statusText);
    })
    .always(function () {
      console.log('the end');
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can authenticate the user from the backend with Java.

After the authentication, either the password is wrong or correct. Based on this result, give a link as the return result respectively and set a status for the current user in the session or cookie.

Of course, when rendering the authenticated page, you need to check is the session is valid or not to decide whether to display content or not.

You can utilize php or asp or any dynamic web language for assistance.